# Getting InvalidImageFormatException as I try pass image to AWS Rekognition

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, axios, amazon-rekognition

I get `InvalidImageFormatException` as I am trying to pass an image to `AWS Rekognition`. I make an HTTP request to an [Image URL](http://www.xsjjys.com/data/out/43/WHDQ-511895361.jpg), download the image and pass the buffer to the aws function.

Here is the code for it:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const axios = require('axios');
let rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition({apiVersion: '2016-06-27', region: 'us-east-1'});

let url = 'http://www.xsjjys.com/data/out/43/WHDQ-511895361.jpg'

axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})
    .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let params = {
                    Image: {
                            Bytes: response.data
                    },
                    Attributes: ['ALL']
            };

            rekognition.detectFaces(params, (err, data) => {
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                    else console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I do not understand what could be the reason for this error. It works for other images but throws an error for some of the images. What could be the reason for this?

Here is the trace for this:

```
{ InvalidImageFormatException: Invalid image encoding
        at Request.extractError (/home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
        at Request.callListeners (/home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
        at Request.emit (/home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
        at Request.emit (/home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
        at Request.transition (/home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
        at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
        at /home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
        at Request.<anonymous> (/home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
        at Request.callListeners (/home/suhail/nodejs/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
    message: 'Invalid image encoding',
    code: 'InvalidImageFormatException',
    time: 2018-04-03T13:28:43.404Z,
    requestId: 'edd8fccf-3742-11e8-95a3-c58fca411044',
    statusCode: 400,
    retryable: false,
    retryDelay: 55.96279161227613 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You image link "http://www.xsjjys.com/data/out/43/WHDQ-511895361.jpg" redirects to an HTML page:

```
curl -v "http://www.xsjjys.com/data/out/43/WHDQ-511895361.jpg"    (510ms)
*   Trying 144.76.74.241...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.xsjjys.com (144.76.74.241) port 80 (#0)
> GET /data/out/43/WHDQ-511895361.jpg HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.xsjjys.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 13:59:42 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 178
< Location: http://www.xsjjys.com/511895361.html
< Connection: keep-alive
< Expires: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 13:59:42 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
<
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host www.xsjjys.com left intact
```

This means that you are passing HTML data instead of image data, which is why Rekognition doesn't work with it. Looks like some kind of anti-hotlinking setup on that site. You might need to pass some cookies or a correct HTTP referer header. But for now, i would simply try with a picture hosted elsewhere.